# Using image icon to load a .gif

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel, imageicon

I am having big trouble to load a simple .gif image with the following code

```
   package etc_ejmp;
/*
 * Fig 21.2 AnimadorLogoJPanel.java
 * Animacion de una serie de imagenes*/
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon; 
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FIG21_2_AnimadorLogoJPanel extends JPanel{
    private final static String NOMBRE_IMAGEN ="deitel";// nombre de la imagen
    protected ImageIcon imagenes[];// arreglo de imagenes
    private final int TOTAL_IMAGENES=30;// numero de imagenes
    private int imagenActual =0;// indice de la imagen actual
    private final int RETRASO_ANIMACION=50;// retraso en milisegundos
    private int anchura;
    private int altura;

    private Timer temporizadosAnimacion;

    public FIG21_2_AnimadorLogoJPanel(){
        imagenes = new ImageIcon[TOTAL_IMAGENES];

        // carga 30 imagenes
        for(int cuenta=0;cuenta<imagenes.length; cuenta++){
            imagenes[ cuenta ] = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource(
                      NOMBRE_IMAGEN + cuenta + ".gif" ) );
        }   


        anchura=imagenes[0].getIconWidth();
        altura=imagenes[0].getIconHeight();
    }
}
```

I have tried with

```
imagenes[ cuenta ] = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("deitel0.gif" ) ); // nothing
imagenes[ cuenta ] = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("deitel.gif" ) ); // nothing
```

but it only works with .png. Also if i try to use numbers inside the string, for example "hello01.gif/.png"  --ERROR

the error is;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException   at
 javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)   at
 etc_ejmp.FIG21_2_AnimadorLogoJPanel.<init>(FIG21_2_AnimadorLogoJPanel.java:29) at
 com.ejercDietel.llamada.llamada_cap21_ejemplos.FIG21_2_AnimadorLogoJPanel(llamada_cap21_ejemplos.java:13) at 
 com.ejercDietel.llamada.EXECAP21.<init>(EXECAP21.java:9)   at
 llamadas.CallCap21(llamadas.java:222)  at
 InicioSistemaPruebas.main(InicioSistemaPruebas.java:67)
```

I don't know what I am missing, it is like the compiler doesn't see the images with .gif format also with number in the file-name.

The name of the images are

```
deitel0.gif
deitel1.gif
deitel10.gif
deitel11.gif
deitel12.gif
deitel13.gif
deitel14.gif
deitel15.gif
deitel16.gif
deitel17.gif
deitel18.gif
deitel19.gif
deitel2.gif
deitel20.gif
deitel21.gif
deitel22.gif
deitel23.gif
deitel24.gif
deitel25.gif
deitel26.gif
deitel27.gif
deitel28.gif
deitel29.gif
deitel3.gif
deitel4.gif
deitel5.gif
deitel6.gif
deitel7.gif
deitel8.gif
deitel9.gif
```

Comment: *"it is like the compiler doesn't see the images"*  The compiler never looks for the images.  It is the run-time that must be producing the message.

Comment: What are the actual names of the image files? I have to wonder if you need to do some 0 padding of your String.

Comment: 1) BTW: By the time of deployment these will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource] that must be accessed by `URL` rather than `File`. 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes i know is a kind of joking way to say it xD.

Comment: *"i know is a kind of way to say it"* What are you referring to?

Comment: Where are the images located? By using just the file name as the relative path, you're saying the images are in the same package as class calling it. If you have them at the root of the classpath the you need a leading `/` in front of the file name.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i was refering to a "way to say something" jejeje sorry

Comment: @peeskillet something like this? "/"+NOMBRE_IMAGEN + cuenta + ".gif"

Comment: Why don't you answer the first part of the question first. Then I can answer yours

Comment: I assume that the images are from Deitel's How to Program Java, 9th edition. If so, what chapter? And where are the images relative to your class files?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yup they are from that book, chapter 21 FIG21.2, by now the images are in the classpath, but i tried with both classpath and inside a filefolder but the result is the same.

Comment: @peeskillet At the moment that i read your comment, I tried with the "\" but the result is the same

Comment: Please answer `Where are the images located?` in the form of something like `src/my/images/are/here`. We need to know exactly where your images are.

Comment: Sorry hehe @peeskillet
src/(images are here) 
********
src/file.java
src/alltheimages

Comment: If your images are `src/image.png` the you should use the path `/image.png`

Comment: @peeskillet 
Something like this?;
`imagenes[ cuenta ] = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("/deitel0.gif" ) );`

Comment: @peeskillet yes same error.

Comment: @DouglasLeekam: Please have a look at how to [add Images to Java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), though this link has already been provided, inside [__info__](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) of [tag:embedded-resource], before. I hope it helps.

Comment: If you haven't already solved the problem, consider posting a [simple runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy-paste-compile-run that demonstrates the problem. The path seems to be correct (i.e. /image.png given your image is in  src/image.png) so the problem may be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149153/loading-animated-gif-from-jar-file-into-imageicon) link.

It Appears to have a few good answer's on gif's with image icon.

Hope this helps

EDIT:
Are you sure your image is in the correct path? 
or the path is correct, it looks as though this is the problem

```
for(int cuenta=0;cuenta<imagenes.length; cuenta++){
        imagenes[ cuenta ] = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource(
                  NOMBRE_IMAGEN + cuenta + ".gif" ) );
    }
```

Is your image in your class path or in another directory, if its in your jar, then make sure you use the full path, eg `com\\myprogram\\image01.gif`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it looks clearly that a requested image(file) was not found.
check if all files really exist.
Also check the **case-sensitivity** of the file names.
maybe there is something like deitel22 **.GIF**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Java does not like .gif extension, it is not the type of file but just the extension. I tested using .png files and works fine. I just copied and rename the same files, same directory from .gif to .png and run the applications... what do you think, it worked!