# How can I pause/sleep/wait in a java swing app?

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating an animation using JLabel,

```
public void updateLabels() {
      label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new Paint().getScaledImage(paint[currentIndexLabel].imageCALA,300,300)));
      label_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new Paint().getScaledImage(paint[currentIndexLabel].imageStates,300,300)));
      label_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new Paint().getScaledImage(paint[currentIndexLabel].imageStrategies,300,300)));
      label_3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new Paint().getScaledImage(paint[currentIndexLabel].imagekD,300,300)));

      currentIndexLabel++;
}
```

and I have a button that updates the labels

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        while (currentIndexLabel != paint.length-1) {
            updateLabels();
        }
    }
});
```

But, I don't know how to wait, say for example 1000ms, until next change. When I add this:

```
try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e){}
```

into my ActionListener:

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           while (currentIndexLabel!=paint.length-1) {
             updateLabels();
             try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e){}
       }
    }
 });
```

its not working. It just stopping for a while and I don't see changes between the first and last frames. Is it possibile to Wait 1000ms without stopping the program? When I delete the while loop and try section, and click my button it is changing pretty well...

How can I do this?

Comment: try looking into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149153/loading-animated-gif-from-jar-file-into-imageicon. Seems like much more reasonable approach to load directly animated gif than using four labels

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `Thread#sleep` method in swing applications in **main** thread will cause the GUI to freeze (since the thread sleeps, events cannot take place). `Thread#sleep` method in swing applications is only allowed to be used only by [SwingWorkers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), and this in their `#doInBackround` method.

In order to wait in a swing application (or do something periodically), you will have to [use a Swing Timer.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) Take a look at an example i have made:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer; //Note the import

public class TimerExample extends JFrame {
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 1000;
    private Timer timer;

    public TimerExample () {
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(200, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, e -> {
            System.out.println("Current Time is: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        });
        //timer.setRepeats(false); //Do it once, or repeat it?
        JButton button = new JButton("Start");
        button.addActionListener(e -> timer.start());
        getContentPane().add(button);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TimerExample().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Output after "Start" button is pressed:

> Current Time is: Mon Feb 25 13:30:44 EET 2019
>
> Current Time is: Mon Feb 25 13:30:45 EET 2019
>
> Current Time is: Mon Feb 25 13:30:46 EET 2019

As you can see, Timer's action listener fires every second.

**So in your case:**

```
timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, e -> {
    if (currentIndexLabel != paint.length-1) {
        upateLabels();
        timer.restart(); //Do this check again after 1000ms
    }
});
button.addActionListener(e -> timer.start());
```

Comment: But how to use it in my code, i see that you replace event of ActionListener, when i trying to make similar thing it doesn't working :D

Comment: hmm i have error in this place, my compliator underline whole text which is comming from you. `Multiple markers at this line
 - Line breakpoint:MyCanvasInWindow 
  [line: 95] - MyCanvasInWindow(Paint[])
 - The constructor Timer(int, (<no type> e) 
  -> {}) is undefined`

Comment: @Potato Hmmm...What java version do you use?

Comment: @Potato Also did you notice Timer's package? `import javax.swing.Timer;`

Comment: haha i noticed that i have different Timer in my imports, but stil i have error with that arrow `Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to 
  complete FormalParameterList
 - Syntax error on token "->", @ expected
 - Syntax error, insert "[ ]" to complete Dimension`