# How to make delay and delete a text?

Tags: java, swing, awt

First post!
I'm beginner in java.

My code use switch/case for display an CardLayout in relation with text in "codeCD".

I want to display CardLayout[1-7] **just for 5 seconds** and **delete** text in "codeCD" for return to cardLayout[0] 'menu'.

I test method "sleep and wait" but didn't work. I don't know how use sleep method with try and catch.

```java
//++zone JTextField++

        ZoneText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,25));

        ZoneText.setBackground(Color.decode("#0d141e"));
        ZoneText.add(codeCD);

        codeCD.requestFocus(true);
        codeCD.setColumns(7);
        codeCD.setOpaque(false);

        //**check input on textfield**
        codeCD.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                super.keyTyped(e);

                if (codeCD.getText().length() >= 7 ) // limit textfield to 7 characters
                    e.consume();


                switch (codeCD.getText()) {
                    //---CARDLAYOUT 1---
                    case "6524875":
                        pile.show(pileCard, listContent[1]);
                        break;

                    //---CARDLAYOUT 2---
                    case "7854862":
                        pile.show(pileCard, listContent[2]);
                        break;

                    //---CARDLAYOUT 3---
                    case "8632547":
                        pile.show(pileCard, listContent[3]);
                        break;

                    //---CARDLAYOUT 4---
                    case "1447559":
                        pile.show(pileCard, listContent[4]);
                        break;

                    //---CARDLAYOUT 5---
                    case "3567487":
                        pile.show(pileCard, listContent[5]);
                        break;

                    //---CARDLAYOUT 6---
                    case "5556897":
                        pile.show(pileCard, listContent[6]);
                        break;

                    //---CARDLAYOUT 7---
                    case "3558774":
                        pile.show(pileCard, listContent[7]);
                        break;

                    //---MENU DEFAULT---
                    default:
                        pile.show(pileCard, listContent[0]);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        //--zone JTextField--
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pause/sleep/wait in a java swing app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865088/how-can-i-pause-sleep-wait-in-a-java-swing-app)

Comment: Thanks for comment. I check that.

Comment: I don't understand how to use timer in my code... :'(

Comment: And we cannot help you unless we have a [mcve]

Comment: *I don't understand how to use timer in my code* - and we don't know what you find confusing about a working example. The basic steps are: 1) you show the card. 2) you start the Timer. 3) when the fires you stop the timer and reset the card.

Comment: @camickr *"when the fires you stop the timer"* Since the problem needs only a single firing, `settRepeats(false)` may be of value here.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, that would be better (and easier)

Comment: [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)